# What does `svelte-kit sync` do?

Tags: typescript, vite, svelte, sveltekit

I've checked the [svelte-kit sync docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/cli#svelte-kit-sync) and the [discussion around it](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/4165) and even tried searching Stack Overflow and asking AI.

My understanding is it generates `tsconfig.json` and is for setting up the project with typescript. When I delete my `tsconfig.json` and run it, nothing seems to happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It creates the TS files for the generated types for `load` functions and actions that allow you to have strongly typed data transfer to the page properties `data` and `form`.

There are two `tsconfig.json` files, one is generated, the other is *not*.
Only the one within the `.svelte-kit` directory is generated.

All these files are also created/updated by the dev server. The `sync` command is helpful for running separate builds.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! So, when you say "running separate builds" you mean it's useful for having a setup where you can build the same project in different ways?

Comment: I mean e.g. a clean install in a CI pipeline where the dev server is never run at all, so the types would not be there otherwise.